# VBA how to store timestamp in variable

Tags: vba, datetime, timestamp

I am working on processing of log or history file. In column 1 there is timestamp like this Wed Mar 01 22:08:01 EST 2017.
I am copying the entire contents of the sheet into 2d variant array for further processing. Now I want to store this timestamp as date or datetime to further process it.

but if I do

dim dTimeStamp as date

and in the loop use it to store the value of column1 
dTimeStamp = cdate(vbaseArray(I,1))

it gives me typemismatch error.

Is there a way I can store timestamp value as date or datetime?
Please suggest.

Comment: Hi @jay - Couple things: First in `cdate(vbaseArray(I,1))` you have an 'L' in row index, not sure if this is the problem or just typo when pasting here but wanted to point it out... Next is if you used `Range.Value2` to read a range into an array I believe Value2 removes date formatting... Lastly, I am not sure the format 'Wed Mar 01 22:08:01 EST 2017' can be converted to date using cdate- so 2 options: 1) try `dateValue` or 2) if that doesn't work you might have to write your own date conversion function from the format of your timestamp above to a date, wouldn't be too tricky. -TheSilkCode

Comment: Hi @SilkCode, Thank you for quick response. 'L' is the row index from the loop. I did not paste the entire code here . I tried datevalue too but its giving me the same type mismatch error.I need to think about writing my own conversion function.

Comment: ahh gotcha, makes sense. Try those other 2 and let me know if works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert that string into a date automatically, so you have to parse it. Generally, `DateValue` is a little more forgiving than `CDate`.

From the immediate windows

```
?datevalue(mid("Wed Mar 01 22:08:01 EST 2017",5,15))
3/1/2017
```

That will always give you the current year. It cuts of the day of week and stops after the time.

If you need the year, or you just want to be more robust, I'd use a function like

```
Function ConvertDate(ByVal sDate As String) As Date

    Dim vaSplit As Variant

    vaSplit = Split(sDate, Space(1))

    ConvertDate = DateValue(vaSplit(1) & Space(1) & vaSplit(2) & ", " & vaSplit(5)) + TimeValue(vaSplit(3))

End Function
```

From the immediate window

```
?convertdate("Wed Mar 01 22:08:01 EST 2017")
3/1/2017 10:08:01 PM
```