# datediff function to compare minute range

Tags: vba, range, datediff

I am copying all the data in the sheet into variant array. Column 1 has timestamp like following.

> Thu Mar 02 01:14:28 EST 2017

I want to process all the rows within timespan of 1 minute. I am using datediff function to find out the difference in minute. But somehow it is not working as per expectation.
Here is the code.

```
    For i = 1 To UBound(vBaseArray)
          dSavedDate = convertDate(vBaseArray(i,1)) 'function to convert string to date
.....          some code
          For j = i To UBound(vBaseArray) 'function to convert string to date

               If DateDiff("n", dSearchDate, dSavedDate) >= 1 And DateDiff("n", dSearchDate, dSavedDate) <= 2 Then

                 ----some code
```

but the result is not as per expectation
if dSavedDate  is Thu Mar 02 01:14:28 EST 2017 then
if statement is returning me following timestamps

> Thu Mar 02 01:12:24 EST 2017
>
> Thu Mar 02 01:12:44 EST 2017
>
> Thu Mar 02 01:12:40 EST 2017
>
> Thu Mar 02 00:47:12 EST 2017

whereas I want timestamps which will be >= 1 minute of dSavedDate

what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it `dSavedDate` that has a value of "Thu Mar 02 01:14:28 EST 2017" or is that the value of `vBaseArray(i,1)`?  If it isn't `dSavedDate`, what **is** the value of `dSavedDate`?  And what is the value of `dSearchDate`?  And do you have any `On Error` statements in your code that might be masking errors?

Comment: yes, the value of dSavedDate  is Thu Mar 02 01:14:28 EST 2017. dSearchDate has the value of all timestamps in column 1 which are within certain criteria. mainly the 4 values which I gave below. but obviously they are not correct

Comment: If `dSavedDate` is Thu Mar 02 01:14:28 EST 2017 then `convertDate` hasn't worked - if it is the function I saw as an answer to one of your other questions, it should be returning a date, not a value like you have shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` variables are represented internally as `Double`, with the time portion as a fractional day to the right of the decimal.  You can just subtract them directly and use a delta to see if they're within a minute of each other:

```
Public Function WithinOneMinute(first As Date, second As Date) As Boolean
    Const ONE_MINUTE As Double = 1 / 24 / 60
    Dim difference As Date
    difference = Abs(first - second)
    WithinOneMinute = difference <= ONE_MINUTE
End Function
```

Then you can call it in your loop like this:

```
    For i = 1 To UBound(vBaseArray)
      dSavedDate = convertDate(vBaseArray(i, 1))
      For j = i To UBound(vBaseArray)
           If Not WithinOneMinute(dSearchDate, dSavedDate) Then
```

Comment: One minor issue - the OP wants >=1 and <=2.

Comment: Won't that just allow anything <-1 Or >1 ?

Comment: @YowE3K - Huh? "I want to process all the rows within timespan of 1 minute." I actually think the original version *without* the `Not` was probably what the OP wanted, but now that I compare the top of the question to the bottom...

Comment: Yeah - the question is somewhat confusing - there is also the statement "I want timestamps which will be >= 1 minute of dSavedDate".  The code is certainly trying to do >=1 and <=2, so I assume it means ones that are within the one minute period after 1 minute after `dSavedDate`.

Comment: @YowE3K - If so, it's just a matter of taking out the `Abs` call. We'll see if the OP wants to chime in.

Comment: @YowE3K - If so, the OP should probably pursue that on the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42810055/4088852).

Comment: Hi, Forgive for 1) late reply, I was on break. 2) for posting a a confusing description. But the suggestion given by @Comintern work for my problem. If WithinOneMinute(dSearchDate, dSavedDate) Then - gives me the records which match the criteria. there is no  need for 'NOT'

Comment: If I want to process records within 2 minutes, do I divide by 120 in the function like following? Const ONE_MINUTE As Double = 1 / 24 / 60

Comment: @Jay - Wrong way - that would be half a minute.  It's 1 day divided by 24 hours divided by 60 minutes.  You could also do `Const TWO_MINUTES As Double = ONE_MINUTE * 2` if you need to use both of them.